# How To Change My Post Url in Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

I want to know how can I change my post url in the given manner in **wordpress**

Currently It is like

www.example.com/categoy/post-url

I want to change it to 
www.example.com/page/category/post-url

how can I do this?

Comment: posts are not a part of your pages? Two different boxes for wordpress.

Comment: Will your categories only ever be listed under the one page, or do you envisage them being under different pages? If the former, just add the page slug to the category base in the Permalinks settings. If the latter, then I don't think that's possible as how would WP know which page to send a particular category to if it's listed under more than one page?

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @stender, a Post is independent of a Page, but it can be shown on a page.

A post has its own URL as does a Page.

However, I have a feeling you are trying ton set the default structure of your post URLs.  This is called a `Permalink`.

To define your Permalinks, log into the WordPress Admin Dashboard:-
* Click on Settings
* Click on Permalinks
* You could choose one of the predefined structures. If you need to make your own, you need to stick with using a combination of the **Available tags** shown under **Custom Structure**.

Hope that helps.  If I have missed your point, please try adding more information to your question.